# Neteller error: The Account ID/Email or Secure ID you entered is not valid. Please correct your account information and try again

Tags: php

In my neteller test transaction, I am getting

> The Account ID/Email or Secure ID you entered is not valid. Please correct your account information and try again.

Account ID and Secure ID for my test transaction is

- Account ID: 458415554241
- Secure ID: 896365
- Currency: USD
  Please help me

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact Neteller, not SO.

Comment: No. I'm using test account.

Comment: If Neteller's test account does not work you need to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

This Account ID does not belong to a valid test member account. Please check section "Test Member Accounts" in the NETELLER REST API guide for a list of all test accounts.

If you don't have a copy of the REST API guide, please send an email to the Merchant Support team. You can find their email here: https://merchant.neteller.com/merchflux/public/index